# Instantiate class manually every time when method get called NestJS

Tags: nestjs

I have a service which needs to instantiate other class every time when method get called.
E.g.

```js
class SomeClass { ... }

@Injectable()
class SomeService {
  constructor(...) {}

  async doStuff() {
    new SomeClass() // new instance every time;
  }
}
```

How can i inject it (**SomeClass**) properly, and create instance of it every time when method **doStuff** get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're needing to instantiate the class everytime for **only that method**, then what you're already doing is fine. No reason to bring in dependency injection if you're going to be instantiating that class, because Nest's DI system will instantiate it for your otherwise